# How do I change the server character set?

Tags: oracle, unicode

I want to test if my code runs well on combinations of single byte and multi-byte character sets on both the client and server. While I understand how to change it on the client ( using NLS_CHAR or NLS_LANG and making sure the conversion is possible), how do I do it on the server side?

Comment: Nowadays each DB should be set to `AL32UTF8` (or similar). I don't see such a test as relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Globalization Support Guide for whatever version of Oracle you are using will have a chapter on [changing the character set of an existing database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch2charset.htm#NLSPG182).  That is not generally a trivial endeavor, however.  It's not something I would ever consider doing as part of a test.

Realistically, if you want to test how your code behaves with different database character sets, you'd be better served by creating multiple databases (probably each on a separate server/ VM) with different database character sets and then running your test suite on each database in turn.